# Better way to do "echo $x | sed ..." and "echo $x | grep ..."

Tags: shell, grep, sed

I often find this in scripts (and, I have to admit, write it myself):

```
a=$(echo "$x" | sed "s/foo/bar/")
```

or

```
if echo "$x" | grep -q foo
then
    ...
fi
```

Consider "foo" to include some regex stuff.

I feel that there should be - and most likely **is** - a better way to phrase this, one that does not involve two commands and a pipe but wraps the thing into some more compact expression.

I just can't find it. Anybody?

Comment: i expect this expression is used frequently due to a combination of ignorance (not knowing alternatives) and maintainability (knowing alternatives but choosing this as the simpler to understand).  i can tell at a glance what your examples do, but i need a shell reference to figure out the alternatives in grawity's and Dan McG's answers.

Comment: By the way, the preferred method of doing command substitution is with `$()` rather than backticks.

Comment: It is also a good idea to quote expansions so that whitespace is protected: `a="$(echo "$x" | sed "s/foo/bar/")"` and `if echo "$x" | grep foo; …`.

Comment: Good remarks on the $() vs. ``. I see my bash skills are not that great yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you assume a specific shell, there is no better way to do this than “pipe echo to tool” (or just a “tool” itself like [*expr*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/expr.html)); it is all you can really count on with the [traditional Bourne shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html) and/or the [POSIX shell](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html). If you consider other shells, then there are some other built-in possibilities.

*ksh* has

- extra patterns: `?(pattern-list)`, `*(pattern-list)`, `{n}(pattern-list)`, `{n,m}(pattern-list)`, `@(pattern-list)`, `!(pattern-list)`;
- the `%P` *printf* specifier to convert a extended regular expression into a pattern (and `%R` for extended regular expression to pattern);
- the `expr == pattern` condition in `[[ expr ]]` tests;
- the `${param/pattern/replacement}` parameter expansion.

*bash* has

- the `extglob` option to enable most of the extra patterns of *ksh* (no `{n}` and `{n,m}`);
- the `expr == pattern` condition (in `[[ expr ]]` tests);
- the `${param/pattern/replacement}` parameter expansion;
- (in newer versions) the `expr =~ extregexp` condition (in `[[ expr ]]` tests) that can match against extended regular expressions

  - with parenthesized subexpressions and the `BASH_REMATCH` parameter, *sed*-style replacements could be done.

*zsh* has

- its own extended patterns with the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option;
- *ksh*-like extended patterns with the `KSH_GLOB` option;
- the `expr == pattern` condition (in `[[ expr ]]` tests);
- the `${pattern/pattern/replacement}` parameter expansion;
- the `expr =~ extregexp` condition (in `[[ expr ]]` tests) that can match against extended regular expressions,

  - it can use [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) instead of plain extended regular expressions if the RE_MATCH_PCRE option is set,
  - with parenthesized subexpressions, the `MATCH` parameter, and the `match` parameter (or `BASH_REMATCH` with the `BASH_REMATCH` option set), *sed*-style replacements could be done;
- the `zsh/pcre` module that offers `pcre_compile`, `pcre_study`, and `pcre_match` commands and the `-pcre-match` *test* condition (in `[[ expr ]]` tests);
- the `zsh/regex` module that offers the `-regex-match` *test* condition (in `[[ expr ]]` tests).

Comment: Wow. As complete as one could wish for. Definitely a winner.

Answer (score 6):

To replace the sed line, do something like

`${a/foo/bar}` or `${a//foo/bar}`

In the first form, only the first instance is replaced. The second form is a global search & replace.

In your case, it would be

Instead of:

```
if echo $x | grep foo
then
    ...
fi
```

Consider using:

```
if [ $x =~ foo ]
then
    ...
fi
```

Where `foo` is a regular expression.

Comment: In which shells does this work?

Comment: Top one works in sh, which is what I use on our works UNIX system and it should work in bash (I think). Bottom one I know works in bash. Not sure on others; I'm in Windows right now so I cannot check. Should be too hard to open a few different shells to test it however.

Comment: ${a/foo/bar} only allows for pathname expansion-alike matching. Good enough if all you're doing is some find&replace, but not really what I was looking for...

Comment: `if [ $x =~ foo ]` gives an error message here. `if [[ $x =~ foo ]]`, however, works great. Thanks!

Comment: i'm not sure, but i think `[[ ]]` is needed when in an interactive shell, but `[ ]` can be used in a script.

Comment: All these are bashisms, they require bash. In addition, `=~` requires bash >= 3 iirc.

Comment: Iirc also, foo is not a regular expression (as in PCRE) in these examples, but uses wildcards. There's more of these bash goodness in the bash manpage, section "Parameter Expansion". I particularly appreciate things like `${a##foo}` and `${a%%bar}`.

Comment: The match operator `=~` does use regular expressions. This is true, for example: `[[ "abcdddde" =~ ^a.*d+.g* ]]` (that's zero-or-more g's rather than g-wildcard, for example).

Comment: @Peltier: There are the same or similar parameter substitution and regex match features in the Korn shell and the Z shell.

Answer (score 2):

A good posix compatible way for testing if a variable contains a pattern is:

```
test ${var##*foo*} || <do something>;
```

---

The syntax of the [parameter expansion](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) is:

```
 ${parameter##pattern}
```

where `pattern` is a [shell pattern](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13).